# TypeError: Failed to execute 'dispatchEvent' on 'EventTarget': parameter 1 is not of type 'Event'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am learning testing in react, now I am trying to create a test for a login page, unfortunately, I am getting an error.

Here is the test file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import Login from 'pages/Auth/Login';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'


// describe what we are testing.....
describe('Login Component', () => {
 
    it('renders the sign in page with a form submission', async () => {
        const { getByTestId, getByPlaceholderText, queryByTestId } = render(
            <Router>
                <Login />
            </Router>
          );

        await act(async () => {
          fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText('Business e-mail'), { target: { value: 'karl@gmail.com' } });
          fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText('Password'), { target: { value: 'password' } });
          fireEvent.click(getByTestId('sign-in'));
    
          expect(getByPlaceholderText('Email address').value).toBe('karl@gmail.com');
          expect(getByPlaceholderText('Password').value).toBe('password');
        });
      });
})
```

When I run `npm test`  I get the following error.

[image]

What do I need to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary `await act(async () =>`
Try like this: `

```
it('renders the sign in page with a form submission', async () => {
    const { getByTestId, getByPlaceholderText, queryByTestId } = render(
        <Router>
            <Login />
        </Router>
      );
      fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText('Business e-mail'), { target: { value: 'karl@gmail.com' } });
      fireEvent.change(getByPlaceholderText('Password'), { target: { value: 'password' } });
      fireEvent.click(getByTestId('sign-in'));

      expect(getByPlaceholderText('Email address').value).toBe('karl@gmail.com');
      expect(getByPlaceholderText('Password').value).toBe('password');
  });
```

`